# How far can one reduce the need for knowledge of differentiation in order to find this integral?

Tags: integration, derivatives, probability-distributions

Suppose for measurable $A\subseteq \mathbb (0,+\infty),$
$$
\Pr(X_i\in A) = \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_i)} \int_A u^{\alpha_i-1} e^{-u} \, du
$$
for $i=1,2,$ and $X_1,X_2$ are independent. In the course of deriving the probability density function of $Y = X_1/X_2,$ I am wondering **what method involves the smallest amount of prerequisite knowledge of differentiation and its relationship with integration.**

We have
$$
\Pr(Y\le x) = \Pr\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2} \le x\right)
= \iint\limits_{ \begin{smallmatrix}
0\,\le\,u \\ 0\,\le\,v \\ u/v\,\le\,x 
\end{smallmatrix}}
f_{X_1,X_2} (u,v)\, d(u,v).
$$
One way of evaluating this integral says
\begin{align}
s & = u/v, \\
t & = v, \\[6pt]
d(s,t) & =\frac{\partial(s,t)}{\partial(u,v)} \, d(u,v) = \frac{d(u,v)} v \\[6pt]
t\, d(s,t) & = d(u,v), \\[6pt]
u & = st, \\
v & = t,
\end{align}
and so on. Plainly this involves differentiation.

Another way is this:
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^{vx}
\frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)} u^{\alpha_1-1} e^{-u}
\cdot
\frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_2)} v^{\alpha_2-1} e^{-v} \, du  \right) \, dv
$$
So we write
\begin{align}
& \frac d {dx} \int_0^\infty \left( \int_0^{vx} \cdots \, du \right) \,dv \\[8pt]
= {} & \int_0^\infty \left( \frac d {dx} \int_0^{vx} \cdots \, du \right) \, dv \quad \text{??}
\end{align}
and so on.

Maybe we can reasonably say that you don't need to know as much about differentiation for this approach, but the two question marks correspond to something substantial.

We can also do this: $w= u/v$ and $dw = du/v$,
and then we get
$$
\int_0^\infty \left( \int _0^x    
\frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)}
(wv)^{\alpha_1-1} e^{-wv} (v\, dw) \right) \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_2)}
v^{\alpha_2-1} e^{-v} \, dv.
$$
Since the bounds of integration in the inner integral do not depend on $v,$ and since the function being integrated is nonnegative, this becomes
$$
\int_0^x \left( \int_0^\infty \frac 1 {\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)}
(wv)^{\alpha_1-1} e^{-wv} v^{\alpha_2} e^{-v} \, dv \right) \,dw.
$$ 
Now we have
$$
\Pr(Y\le x) = \int_0^x \big( \text{some function of $w$} \big) \, dw.
$$
We can conclude, without mentioning differentiation, that that function of $w$ is the desired probability density function. Then we still have an integral to evaluate, and we finally get, for $A\subseteq\mathbb(0,+\infty),$
$$
\Pr(Y\in A) = \int_A \frac {\Gamma(\alpha_1+\alpha_2)} {\Gamma(\alpha_1)\Gamma(\alpha_2)}
\cdot \frac{w^{\alpha_1-1}}{(1+w)^{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}} \, dw.
$$

But when we write $w= u/v$ and $dw = du/v,$ we are still relying on some knowledge of differentiation, namely the chain rule.

**Is there any way to take this a step further in eliminating a need for knowledge of differentiation?**

Comment: Where is a chain rule in $d(w/3) =(dw)/3$?

Comment: The chain rule tells us that $d \sin(3x) = \cos(3x)\cdot 3\, dx = \cos u \, du$ because $3\, dx = du. \qquad$

Comment: @NCh : $\qquad \uparrow \qquad$

Comment: I know. And you said in the end of the OP that equality $d(w/3)=(dw)/3$ requires chain rule.

Comment: @NCh : Its use in this context involves the chain rule.